# How to connect FreeBSD Jail to network

Tags: freebsd, jail

So recently I successfully installed and configured a `freebsd jail` and I would like to install 
software within my jail but I cannot connect to the network. I'm trying to setup an `apache+php+mysql` installation within the jail and have the webserver accessible by users. Here is my `rc.conf` for the jail.

```
...
jail_enable="YES"   # Set to NO to disable starting of any jails
jail_list="mambo2"     # Space separated list of names of jails

jail_mambo2_rootdir="/usr/jails/j01"     # jail's root directory
jail_mambo2_hostname="mambo2.ug"  # jail's hostname
jail_mambo2_ip="192.168.100.174"           # jail's IP address
jail_mambo2_devfs_enable="YES"          # mount devfs in the jail
jail_mambo2_devfs_ruleset="mambo2_ruleset" # devfs ruleset to apply to jail
```

here is my jail `ifconfig` output

```
mambo2# ifconfig
rl0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8<VLAN_MTU>
        ether 00:c1:28:00:48:db
        media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
        status: active
plip0: flags=108810<POINTOPOINT,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST,NEEDSGIANT> metric 0 mtu 1500
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
mambo2#
```

It does not show the IP address I configured within `/etc/rc.conf`. But, when I list the running jails, it shows the right IP address.

Here is a list of `jails` running

```
[root@mambo /usr/home/jtumusiime]# jls
JID  IP Address      Hostname                      Path
5  192.168.100.174 mambo2.ug                     /usr/jails/j01
```

I also created a `/etc/resolv.conf` for nameservers. This was not in existence so I'm not quite sure if it is necessary?

```
mambo2# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver  192.168.100.251
nameserver  8.8.8.8

mambo2#
```

my host has 4 ip addresses, 3 public and one private: `192.168.100.173`

I tried creating a jail using `ezjail` and this does not work out.

```
[root@mambo /usr/src]# ezjail-admin update -p -i
Error: Cannot find your copy of the FreeBSD source tree in .
  Consider using 'ezjail-admin install' to create the base jail from an ftp server.
[root@mambo /usr/src]#
```

I have an updated copy of `freebsd 7.1` source tree from SVN in `/usr/src/`

```
[root@mambo /usr/src]# svn info
Path: .
URL: http://svn.freebsd.org/base/release/7.1.0
Repository Root: http://svn.freebsd.org/base
Repository UUID: ccf9f872-aa2e-dd11-9fc8-001c23d0bc1f
Revision: 243371
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: kensmith
Last Changed Rev: 186660
Last Changed Date: 2009-01-01 01:57:14 +0300 (Thu, 01 Jan 2009)

[root@mambo /usr/src]#
```

and I did

```
#make buildworld
```

while building the first jail i.e `mambo2`

Here is an excerpt of ouput of `ezjail-admin install`

```
...
221 Goodbye.
Trying 193.162.146.4...
Connected to ftp.freebsd.org.
220 ftp.beastie.tdk.net FTP server (Version 6.00LS) ready.
331 Guest login ok, send your email address as password.
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
200 Type set to I.
550 pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/i386/7.1-RELEASE/base: No such file or directory.
221 Goodbye.

Could not fetch base from ftp.freebsd.org.
  Maybe your release (7.1-RELEASE) is specified incorrectly or the host ftp.freebsd.org     does not provide that release build.
  Use the -r option to specify an existing release or the -h option to specify an     alternative ftp server.
Querying your ftp-server... The ftp server you specified (ftp.freebsd.org) seems to         provide the following builds:
Trying 193.162.146.4...
total 10
drwxrwxr-x  13 1006  1006   512 Feb 20  2011 8.2-RELEASE
drwxrwxr-x  13 1006  1006   512 Apr 10  2012 8.3-RELEASE
lrwxr-xr-x   1 1006  1006    16 Jan  7  2012 9.0-RELEASE -> i386/9.0-RELEASE
drwxrwxr-x   7 1006  1006  1024 Feb 19  2012 ISO-IMAGES
-rw-rw-r--   1 1006  1006   637 Nov 23  2005 README.TXT
drwxrwxr-x   5 1006  1006   512 Nov  2 02:59 i386
```

I do not want to upgrade my `freebsd` installation. I have googled around; but all in vail.

Thank you

Comment: Re: your ezjail problems - double-check your `ezjail.conf` file and make sure the source tree path is specified correctly. It sounds like your configuration file is missing or malformed. /// <Obligatory Lecture> You know 7.1 is a dead release, right? (and 7.4 - the last supported 7.x - dies in February per http://freebsd.org/security). The upgrade to 8.x (or even 8.x->9.x) isn't that painful. </Obligatory Lecture>

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to add an entry to /etc/rc.conf to ensure the alias is recreated on reboot. Also, you might consider using ezjail.

Comment: Thanks, I did that too. About using ezjail, if you read my question, you know that did go well.

Comment: Right, sorry, missed that. Personally, I've had good luck with ezjail, but I let it do everything except the network setup and the creation of the initial zfs filesystem for the jail. That seems to help things go well.

Answer (score 3):

For this case, configuring the jail IP as a virtual IP on the interface rl0 via the host fixed it:

```
#ifconfig rl0 192.168.100.174 netmask 255.255.255.0 alias
```